# How to understand squared parenthesis and comma in r data frame

Tags: r

I am following a paper example where the leukemia.train data frame has 38 obs and 7130 variables. My understanding of the syntax is that y1 will be that part of leukemia.train corresponding to column [2]. When I print y1, I obtain values that instead correspond to column 7130. Why? I am not understanding something...

```r
y1 <- leukemia.train[, dim(leukemia.train)[2]] 
> y1
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: `dim()` returns the number of rows [1] and the number of columns [2]. So `[, dim(leukemia.train)[2]]` returns all rows in the last column, which is 7130 presumably.

Answer (score 0):

`dim(x)` is a vector with the dimensions of `x` — that is, the numbers of its rows and columns (for a two-dimensional matrix/data.frame).

In the case of `leukemia.train`, the dimension vector will look like this:

```
[1] 38 7130
```

Next, you are taking the second element of it: `dim(leukemia.train)[2]`, and use it to subset the entire matrix.

Your statement is thus equivalent to:

```
y1 <- leukemia.train[, 7130]
```

---

Another small but important detail: After the assignment, `y1` will *not* “be a part of” the original matrix. Instead it’s a *copy* of the part of the matrix that you’re subsetting (i.e. its 7130th column).

Comment: what do you mean by sub setting the entire matrix? thanks

Comment: @user11465312 Are you familiar with the concept of subsetting in linear algebra? Either way, check out [a programming book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Comment: I am not familiar with that concept, but thanks a lot, I ll look at the book